# Mark own question as duplicate?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I had asked a question few months back & forgotten about it. Before asking the same question again I checked on my account for stackoverflow.com but could not find it, so I asked the same question again.

How can I mark my own question as duplicate of the previously asked question?

Answer (score 4):

Flag it for moderator attention, and say it's a dupe of the one you want to keep around

Comment: Cant i keep both around? Answers in both of them are useful.

Comment: @chantz we can merge them together

Comment: ok. thanks. I will flag it as such.

Comment: Done <extra chars>